Is NFC peer-to-peer supported on iOS?
I a planning an app that exchanges data using NFC peer-to-peer. On iOS, is it possible to use NFC peer-to-peer in my own apps?

No. CoreNFC does not support this.

As Google/Android removed the NFC Peer-to-Peer" mode, I don't expect that Apple will introduce this feature in the next iOS releases, sorry. Better use Bluetooth (Low Energy) or Wi-Fi for this.

@MichaelFehr Oh, didn't know they removed it! Do you have a source for that?

@Paulw11 Sad to hear, but thanks for the info.

This information is from @Andrew: "Note while Google removed Beam (Android peer to peer) from Android 10 stock/open source offering, they did allow manufacturers to add it back in and support it themselves, this was probably to allow some custom hardware manufacturers to still offer it."
